# PAM Authentication with LDAP on Debian Jessie Not Finding LDAP Users

Tags: debian, openldap, pam

Debian Jessie (specifically, Debian Server Wheezy x64 with testing repos)

OpenLDAP 2.4.39

libpam-ldapd 0.9.4-1

Upon installing libpam-ldapd, the dpkg configuration asked for my LDAP address information (ldapi:\\localhost) and correctly detected my server base.

I've tried to follow the [Debian Wiki articles](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM), but there are references to files that do not exist and scant information to indicate how I might be sure LDAP is being consulted.

I have OpenLDAP configured and the inetorgperson and NIS schemas loaded. The users ought to have all the correct attributes. Right now, I'm just trying to determine if LDAP is even being consulted, because it seems it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `getent passwd`, do you see your LDAP users listed? If not, make sure `libnss-ldapd` is installed, and run `dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldapd` and make sure at least the `passwd` database is enabled (and you'll probably want `group` and `shadow` as well, sooner or later).

If `getent passwd` mentions your LDAP users but you can't auth as one, run `pam-auth-update` and make sure LDAP authentication is enabled and `nslcd` is running.

If `nscd` (or some variant such as `unscd`) is installed, I suggest stopping it while troubleshooting as it could return cached inaccurate data.

Information about what `pam_ldap` is up to is logged to `/var/log/auth.log`; information about what `nslcd` is up to is logged to `/var/log/syslog`; and on the `slapd` side, turning the log level up to `stats` will let you see the actual queries `nslcd` is issuing, whether they were successful, and the number of results returned.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an existing working OpenLDAP server on your network under Debian Jessie then you should be using the following packages :

```
libnss-ldap 
libpam-ldap
```

rather than

```
libnss-ldapd
libpam-ldapd
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

My symptoms were that `getent passwd` works, but logging in with samba and setquota didn't.

After running `dpkg-reconfigure libnss-ldapd` with `passwd`, `group` and `shadow` enabled it now works fine.